# Position fixed and -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Tags: css, cordova, webkit, css-position, webkit-overflow-scrolling

I am using the css trick to make a site feel like an app in Cordova.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

However, that breaks (disappear, bounce) my position:fixed elements. Any ideas on why?

FYI Safari on ios8 works great, the problem it's only when I create the app in cordova (UIWebVier).

Comment: Also having this problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: You can play with z-index, css translations, etc... but in the end what really made a difference was using ios new wkwebview as it would be the equivalent to use a modern version of Safari. The difference in performance is also massive.